# python len method not good

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, methods

So I am trying to do the MacDonald challenge.Given a function with the parameter "name", return the MacDonald version of it, the 1st and 4th letter being capitalized.
If I try the code without any if else and I pass in just "mac" an error occurs.So I said that if the length of name is less than 5 letters, print out that name is too short.Otherwise, do the macdonald version.
However, for some reason len() gives out an error here.

```
def old_macdonald(name):
    firstLetter = name[0].capitalize()
    fourthLetter = name[3].capitalize()
    inBetween = name[1:3]
    last = name[4:]
    newName = firstLetter + inBetween + fourthLetter + last
    if len(newName) < 4:
        print("name is too short.")
    else:
        print(newName)
old_macdonald("mac")
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the error (and traceback) that `len` is giving into your question.

Comment: It's not the `len` that errs, it's `name[3]` - there's no 4th char in "mac".

Comment: @georg: I  was about to mention that, but if you already did it, I won't :-). @StorMy:  you should write `if len(newName) < 4:` before parsing `name` with capitalization &co, otherwise you do unnecessary code for too short names.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `len` is throwing the exception, but just as the version without if condition the string manipulation does.

Do the string manipulation in the `else` part of your code to avoid the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Following Jens' advice, I included the if check above everything else (since you want to terminate the function if the name is too short) and returned in the if-check to break end the function.

```
def old_macdonald(name):
    if len(name)< 4:
        print("name is too short.")
        return
    firstLetter = name[0].capitalize()
    fourthLetter = name[3].capitalize()
    inBetween = name[1:3]
    last = name[4:]
    newName = firstLetter + inBetween + fourthLetter + last
    print(newName)

old_macdonald("mac")
old_macdonald("macdonald")
```

Here is the result
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are still trying to perform the same operations anyway, len is not throwing you an error, the above part of the code is giving you error.

Simply move your code to the else part of function and you should be fine. The reason you need to do this is because you need to check first, and then perform, instead of performing and then checking.